Return a Hashmap with key with values in Spring-Data-JPA
I have this SQL table structure:
create table permissions (id bigint not null, permission varchar(255) not null, role_id bigint not null, primary key (id))
create table roles (id bigint not null, role_name varchar(255) not null, primary key (id))

insert into roles (role_name,id) values ("USER_ADMIN",1)
insert into permissions (permission,role_id,id) values ("write:all",1,10)
insert into permissions (permission,role_id,id) values ("write:key",1,11)
insert into permissions (permission,role_id,id) values ("write:vl",1,12)
insert into permissions (permission,role_id,id) values ("write:ts",1,13)


insert into roles (role_name,id) values ("DB_ADMIN",2)
insert into permissions (permission,role_id,id) values ("red:all",2,20)
insert into permissions (permission,role_id,id) values ("red:key",2,21)
insert into permissions (permission,role_id,id) values ("red:vl",2,22)
insert into permissions (permission,role_id,id) values ("red:ts",2,23)

I have this SQL query which I want to use to select the rows:
"SELECT r.roleName AS roleName, p.permission AS permissions " +
           "FROM Role r " +
           "LEFT JOIN r.permissions p " +
           "WHERE r.roleName in ("USER_ADMIN", "DB_ADMIN")

As a result I want to return the query result as a Map<String, List> where the key is the roleName and the value is a list of permissions:
Map<String, List<String>> rolePermissionsMap = new HashMap<>();

Do you know how this can be archived using Spring Data JPA projection?

In spring jpa

Create Role entity
Create Permission entity
Create one to many relation.
Create repositoryRole and repositoryPermission.
In reposityRole Create method with you query or List findByRoleNameIn(List roleNames)
Call this method - var roles = role Repository.findByRoleNameIn(List.of("user_admin","db_admin"));
And you can transformate List to map
Map<String, Choice> result = roles.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Roles::getName,Roles::gerPermission )


Can you show me code implementation for step 7 please?
